# Problems passing argument to python function with decorator

Tags: python, celery, decorator, python-decorators

I have the following code, which results in this error:

```
TypeError('smallTask() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)',)
```

---

```
@task
def master():
    count = 0
    obj = { 'var1':'val1', 'var2':'val2' }

    while count < 10:
        subtask('smallTask',obj).apply_async()
        count += 1

@task(name='smallTask')
def smallTask(obj):
    print obj
```

Passing a dictionary to a function, I imagine I need to use **kwargs but if I do that, I get the error that the function takes no arguments yet 2 have been supplied.

I assume the issue here is with either the decorator (have a basic understanding of this but not enough to solve the problem) or the [subtask](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html) function in Celery.

I don't have enough python knowledge to really proceed..could anyone give me an idea of what's happening and how I can pass the smallTask function a dictionary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass arguments for a subtask in the `args` keyword argument, which must be a tuple according to the [`celery.subtask()` documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.html#celery.subtask):

```
subtask('smallTask', args=(obj,)).apply_async()
```

or use the [`Task.subtask()`](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.subtask) method *on* your `smallTask` task, but again pass the arguments as a tuple:

```
smallTask.subtask((obj,)).apply_async()
```

Alternatively, use star arguments with the [`Task.s()` method](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/reference/celery.app.task.html#celery.app.task.Task.s):

```
smallTask.s(obj).apply_async()
```

The [subtasks documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#subtasks) you yourself linked to use a tuple in the examples; arguments and keyword arguments are two pieces of data that Celery has to store for you until it can run that task, *then* it'll apply those arguments and keyword arguments for you.

But the `celery.subtask()` function takes more than just the arguments and keyword arguments for your task; it also takes additional options. In order to work with *arbitrary* arguments  (positional or keyword) to your task, *and* support other arguments that are *not* passed to your task, the function signature has no choice but to accept positional arguments as an explicit tuple, and keyword arguments as an explicit dictionary.

The `Task.s()` method does not accept any arguments other than what the task itself would accept, so it does support passing arguments as if you called the task directly. Internally, this uses catch-all arguments: `Task.s(*args, **kwarg)`, and just passes the captured arguments as a tuple and dictionary on to `Task.subtask()`.

Comment: Ok that definitely works and happy to accept but at this point it may as well be witchcraft.  Would you mind elaborating a little more please?  I can research keyword arguments, but why is obj a tuple?  Thanks,

Comment: Thanks, that helps a lot.  It's more a case of me not understanding enough python for the docs to be useful.  Need to read up on positional and keyword arguments.  Really appreciate you taking the time to answer.  Thanks!

Comment: What if I have two subtasks that have declarations like `my_first_task(arg11, arg12, arg13=False, arg14=True)` and `my_second_task(arg21, arg22, arg23=False, arg24=True)`. Then how do we pass arguments to them when calling `group([my_first_task.s(...), my_second_task.s(...)])`? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinGhaboosi: `Task.s()` can be called as if you are calling the task directly. So `group([my_first_task.s(value_for_arg11, value_for_arg12, arg13=perhaps_value_for_arg13), ...])`.